# c++ style "get or create" for map unique_ptr values

Tags: c++, std

I want to make a tree where the nodes have a collection of `unique_ptr` child nodes.

```
struct Node {
    map<int, unique_ptr<Node>> children;
};
```

The typical way is calling `find()`, seeing if it matches `children.end()`, and creating a new if neccessary.  I would love to do the more concise:

```
map<int, unique_ptr<Node>> themap;
themap[5]->children[6] = make_unique<Node>();
```

But while that compiles, `operator[]` is just calling the default constructor on `unique_ptr`, which wraps `nullptr`, so this seg faults.

I came up with something that is able to do this in a one liner:

```
themap.try_emplace(5, make_unique<Node>()).first->second->children.try_emplace(6, make_unique<Node>());
```

However, while `try_emplace` is kind enough not to move my rvalue if it doesn't need to, it still gets constructed every time even if the key is already there.

Is there a better way?

Edit: I should mention, the only reason I'm using pointer at all and not just map<int, Node> is that LeetCode is apparently using an older compiler that doesn't allow a struct to contain itself.  That works fine on latest gcc and clang.

Comment: I'd probably put a `unique_ptr` into a class with an appropriate default constructor, some overloads so that `->` and `*` gets forwarded to the `unique_ptr`, and put that in a map. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no interface on `std::map` to do this, especially not with `unique_ptr`. So you would have to wrap your first suggested approach as the other comment suggests.